# Restrict a CFT to an Account

Tags: aws-cloudformation

How can I restrict a Cloudformation template to a particular account. Can I restrict or have the Cloudformation to validate the AWS Account number with the one that is hard coded? Are there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [CloudFormation Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) that checks the value of `AWS::AccountId`.

Then, reference the condition from each resource so that the resource is only created if the Condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Parameters:
  AccNo:
  Type: Number
Description: Enter the number to be validated
Conditions: 
  Number: !Equals [ !Ref AccNo, AWS::AccountId ]
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
   Condition: Number
   Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
   DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

Comment: Should use substitution !Sub for AccountId